# disable menu bar and dock programmatically in mac

Tags: macos, desktop

i am new to mac programming and i have to perform a task. I need to make an application that will run at startup and cover the complete screen and will not close until my custom passcode is inserted. 
The menu bar and dock needs to be hidden behind this application and the application cannot be closed until the information is given.

So far i have written the code that would run at startup . But i cant seem to disable the menu bar and dock and lock all user actions unless he gives the passcode i want.

What to do !!!!

Comment: The Mac login prompt already does this.

Comment: Have you tried disabling auto-login in the System Preferences -> Accounts panel?  It might save you a lot of work and might actually work.

Comment: You are aware that such an "security" application could be easily bypassed by holding "Shift" during the log-in process which would disable login items? I agree strongly with David, use the loginwindow to prevent other users from using your account!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the Menu-Bar in Swift (Xcode, Mac OS X Application), you do:

```
NSMenu.setMenuBarVisible(false)
```

If you want to show the Menu-Bar again:

```
NSMenu.setMenuBarVisible(true)
```

Please keep in mind, that "setMenuBarVisible" is a class function and does not exist for instances of a class. So the following line is not possible:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu!.setMenuBarVisible(false)
```

And will result in an error, saying, that the func "setMenuBarVisible" is not defined.