# run kiosk .app at startup in mac

Tags: macos, startup, launch, at-command

i want to startup an application (.app) at startup in a GUEST ACCOUNT in mac(snow leopard). THe app disables all shortcuts and dock as well(using kiosk). The user must enter a token number to login . I have made the app but i cant force every other service to stop . If i put it in boot sequence through system->services, the app does not come at front. instead it is launched but is in the doc and i have to left click it to launch it in front. :(
(i want to do this programmatically by editing the boot sequence of mac OS )

Problem is I used kiosk and it only works when my application is in front.

So i need to perform this that i cant figure out.
1) run my app only(after login and NO OTHER SERVICE) and rest of the mac should boot once my app has exited.

Thanks in advance 
for any help that u can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already tried to tell you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848421/disable-menu-bar-and-dock-programmatically-in-mac) that you are probably going the wrong way. If you put something into a user´s login items, it can easily be deactivated by holding "shift" while logging in (which you probably do not want); also, completely hacking your Mac OS Startup routine (if it *can* be done) is a bit too much in my eyes.

You should seriously consider

- using a login/policy banner (realised for example [here](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=2010120813054649)) which would pop up over the loginwindow (so a user has to agree)
- using a loginwindow hook combined with a logout hook to change the user password (e.g. based on a hidden password-list and using dscl -passwd or pwpolicy) once the user logs out. This way you should be able to generate passwords based on a list and validate them (token system)

Yours, Asmus

P.S.: on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848421/disable-menu-bar-and-dock-programmatically-in-mac) you commented on mipadi´s answer that you have found a great link, thought it´s missing. Could you maybe add this, as this might be interesting for other people in the future.

Comment: hmmm...thats a better solution...thanks .. i will look over it. @Asmus only issue is that i need to run this on a guest account and i am not sure if we can use it there.. also i looked up login hook ... i have snow leopard and when i use login hook, my mytest.app is launched but it does not come on the screen, instead an its just an icon on my dock which is annoying... i will look up your solution...thanks for this idea

Comment: first off...thanks asmus for replying to my question.. i have thoroughly studied your link and implemented it to see if it works for me. There is an issue with it, i want the loginwindow to come AFTER the user has selected the guest account so that i can monitor the usage of pc and charge accordingly...

Comment: @asmus... i looked up the loginhook and logout hook..... using both a and b of ur techniques , i can perform what i want.. thanks asmus.. But one should keep in mind that login hooks can run only scripts and not applications...if u give them an extension of .app, they will just open the folder... thought everyone should know this

Comment: You will have to hand over the executable - most likely in YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp ; maybe you want to make it become frontmost (or anything) on being invoked like that (try eg. /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --help)

Comment: this is done...actually the application that was given in the link . i am using that now...just edited it as i wanted.. THANK UUUUUU ASMUS

Comment: No problem! If you like, you could mark my answer as the solution :-)